# Why is applet outdated?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am beginner in Java, And now I am learning Applet.My sir of programmer told me that applet is outdated, Not only applet but AWT and swing are also outdated.Why they are outdated and what is the technique used instead of AWT or Applet?

Comment: Neither Swing nor Applets are not actually "outdated" - at least not in the sense that there is a "replacement". Modern applets are really just Java Web Start (JWS) environments hosted inside browsers. If you need Java *in* a browser, use an Applet (which is "JWS" in anything from the last decade or so). Otherwise, don't.

Comment: @user2864740 But Normally Why more developments doesn't take place in Applet?

Comment: Because of a shrinking/small market share to other technology like Flash (which has almost ubiquitous market penetration) and *huge* improvements in client-side HTML/CSS.

Comment: Because all the money is in smartphones.

Comment: Then Java is not good for server side programming as other technologies used instead of java? @user2864740

Comment: @user3347714 Who said it is "not as good"? Some people like Java (the language) and the ecosystem that comes with it. I work in and prefer C# (it pays my bills). Others Ruby, or NodeJS, or whatever ..

Comment: Applets are not generally used for server-side programming.

Comment: How is java Different from C#, Ruby or others. @user2864740

Comment: @user3347714 Well, I'm gonna stop replying after this, but they are all *different* languages with *different* run-time environments. Use the tool that makes your code/project/development the best (by whatever metrics you use) .. and/or the one that gets you the most money/enjoyment/purpose (again by your metrics) at the end of the day.

Comment: Oracle is only a 200 pound gorilla, not a 500 pound one.

Comment: See [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for my take on applets.  Not so much 'outdated' as a PITA (and always have been).